# How does `gsub` differ from `gsub!` when using hash key as patterns to substitute its values?

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I used `gsub!` to substitute a match with a hash key with its hash value. For example:

```
def replace_string(string = "@ReplaceMe[xyz]@@ReplaceMe[123]@Hello")
  generator_replacements = {
    "@ReplaceMe[xyz]@" => "Time",
    "@ReplaceMe[123]@" => "Date"
  }
  generator_replacements.each{
    |generator, replacement|
    string = string.gsub!(generator.to_s, replacement.to_s)
    puts string
  }
end

replace_string
```

outputs:

1. `TimeDateHello`
2. `TimeDateHello`

I don't understand why `gsub!` substituted all the hash keys at one go rather than with every iteration. When I try using `gsub`, it substitutes with every iteration:

1. `Time@ReplaceMe[123]@Hello`
2. `TimeDateHello`

Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: This isn't valid syntax. You don't use curly braces around method definitions in Ruby. And what is `generated_string`? I have a feeling this isn't your actual, working (or non-working) code. Please edit your question to include your actual code.

Comment: Could you come up with an example that uses less cryptic placeholder names, please?

Comment: What is `generated_string`?

Comment: @Jordan This isn't my actual code, correct. I needed to remove any trace of actual variable names and data before posting on here for confidential reasons. I have now corrected `generated_string` to `string`

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in that regard. The `each` loop is executed element by element and neither `gsub` nor `gsub!` can foresee the future.

This code:

```
replacements = { 'foo' => 'hello', 'bar' => 'world' }
string = 'foo bar!'
replacements.each do |placeholder, value|
  string = string.gsub(placeholder, value)
end
string #=> 'hello world!'
```

is equivalent to:

```
string = 'foo bar!'
string = string.gsub('foo', 'hello') #=> "hello bar!"
string = string.gsub('bar', 'world') #=> "hello world!"
string #=> 'hello world!'
```

with `gsub!` you could write:

```
string = 'foo bar!'
string.gsub!('foo', 'hello') #=> "hello bar!"
string.gsub!('bar', 'world') #=> "hello world!"
string #=> 'hello world!'
```

The main difference is that `gsub!` changes the receiver in-place, whereas `gsub` returns a new string (hence the need to assign it back to `string`).

To perform multiple replacements at once, you can pass a hash to `gsub`:

```
string = 'foo bar!'
string.gsub(/foo|bar/, { 'foo' => 'hello', 'bar' => 'world' })
#=> "hello world!"
```

The regular expression can also be generated programmatically:

```
replacements = { 'foo' => 'hello', 'bar' => 'world' }
string = 'foo bar!'
string.gsub(Regexp.union(replacements.keys), replacements)
#=> "hello world!"
```

Comment: If that's the case, that there's no difference between `gsub` and `gsub!` except for the fact that `gsub!` overwrites the `string`, then why doesn't my function output _Time@ReplaceMe[123]@Hello_ then _TimeDateHello_?

Comment: @QCFia see [Jordan's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728581/how-does-gsub-differ-from-gsub-when-using-hash-key-as-patterns-to-substitut/34729215#comment57203657_34728581), your code isn't valid and we don't know how your method is being called. Please edit your question and include your actual code.

Comment: does that make more sense now??

Comment: @QCFia I get the same output, whether I use `gsub` or `gsub!`.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code so that it works as shown below:

```
def replace_string(generated_string = "@ReplaceMe[xyz]@@ReplaceMe[123]@Hello")
  generator_replacements = {
    "@ReplaceMe[xyz]@" => "Time",
    "@ReplaceMe[123]@" => "Date"
  }
  generator_replacements.each do |generator, replacement|
    string = generated_string.gsub(generator.to_s, replacement.to_s)
    puts string
  end
end
```

With this code using `gsub` I get:

```
Time@ReplaceMe[123]@Hello
@ReplaceMe[xyz]@DateHello
```

and with `gsub!` I get:

```
Time@ReplaceMe[123]@Hello
TimeDateHello
```

The reason for this is that `gsub!` modifies the existing string where as `gsub` does not modify the existing string. Does this help answer your question?